# Attempting to generate & download Google Drive API credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm currently following a tutorial, and I'm on this step:

> Go to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/go, click
> "Enable the Drive API", select the account with the stash and click
> "Download Client Configuration".

I'm assuming Google changed the process for this because these settings aren't here. I also don't see them in the API console. Any suggestions on how I can find this information?

Comment: Here is a Youtube video which will show you how to create installed client credentials.  Under library enable the google drive api https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ

Answer (score 0):

That button used to prompt you a list of existing Google Cloud Platform projects, from which you would have to select one. Then the API would be enabled on the selected project. You can replicate that approach easily by following these steps:

1. If you need to [create a GCP project](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project#create_a_new_google_cloud_platform_gcp_project), adopt this guide. Otherwise you can skip this step.
2. To [enable an API](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project#enable-api) into a GCP project, adhere to those steps.